# Perl how to import my package from another package?

Tags: perl

This is my folder structure:

```
XFolder/
XFolder/YFolder/
XFolder/YFolder/package1.pl
XFolder/package2.pl
```

In `package2.pl`, I have:

```
package X::Pa2
```

In `package1.p1`, I have:

```
package X::Y::Pa1
```

In `package1.pl`, when I do this:

```
use X::Pa2;
```

I get

```
Can't locate X/PA2.pm in @INC (you may need to install the X::Pa2 module)
```

How to fix it please?

I know  where the problem is and I tried to use google to help but I couldn't add my `X::Pa2` to my `@INC` and I don't know if there is a more standard solution from Perl experts

Comment: your packages need a `.pm` extension and usually follow the directory path for their name `X/Pa2.pm` and `X/Y/Pa1.pm`

Comment: @KeepCalmAndCarryOn I changed them to .pm but still the same error :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modules should have the `.pm` extension, and the name of the file should match the name of the package.

To fix:

```
mkdir -p X
mv XFolder/package2.pl X/Pa2.pm

mkdir -p X/Y
mv XFolder/YFolder/package1.pl X/Y/Pa1.pm
```

---

These paths need to be relative to some path found in `@INC`.

If these modules are used my multiple scripts, add the following to your login script:

```
export PERL5LIB=/path/to/lib
```

If these modules are only used by one script, and the base directory is the directory in which the script resides, add the following to your script:

```
use FindBin 1.51 qw( $RealBin );
use lib $RealBin;                    # Or maybe: use lib "$RealBin/lib";
```

or

```
use Cwd qw( abs_path );
use File::Basename qw( dirname );
use lib dirname(abs_path($0));       # Or maybe: use lib dirname(abs_path($0))."/lib";
```

Comment: that didn't change anything :( I changed the extension to .pm and the packages are already as the file name but stil the same error

Comment: Please provide the actual error message returned, and the complete path to the file you are trying to load.

Comment: ikegmai: the files are like this: `X(folder)->Y.pm`, `X(folder)->Y(folder)->Z.pm` and inside Z.pm I do use X::Y and the message is X/Y.pm is not in @INC, INC doen't contains the base folder (which is X) but I am using `use lib ('.');`

Comment: `use lib ('.');` is incorrect and different than what I said you should use. Start by fixing that. Then, if you still get the error, please provide the actual error message returned, and the complete path to the file you are trying to load.

Comment: `Can't locate X/Y.pm in @INC (you may need to install the X::Y module) (@INC contains: . /Library/Perl/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level /Library/Perl/5.18 /Network/Library/Perl/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level /Network/Library/Perl/5.18 /Library/Perl/Updates/5.18.2/darwin-thread-multi-2level /Library/Perl/Updates/5.18.2 /System/Library/Perl/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level /System/Library/Perl/5.18 /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18) at X.pm line 12.` and the path to my file is:

Comment: `/Users/myname/Documents/blabla/ccccc/ggg/x/lib/X/Y`

Comment: Are these modules only used by one script?

Comment: so far yes, maybe later there will be a new moduel at the folder Y (so same folder as Z.pm) that will use the module X::Y

Comment: That's not actually relevant. What's the full path to the script (Is it `/Users/myname/Documents/blabla/ccccc/ggg/x/script.pl`?)

Comment: no, the full path is: `/Users/myname/Documents/blabla/ccccc/ggg/x/lib/X/Y/Z.pm` indeed the Z.pm is a moduel but It is calling a subroutine inside it, and I am doing it because I am developing the moduel so it is easy just to call it.

Comment: That's not a script. What's the full path to the script you've asked `perl` to execute? (If you're not sure, place the following before the `use`: `BEGIN { print "$0\n"; }`)

Comment: I don't have a script yet, I am calling `perl Z.pm` :) should I create a script that calls a subrotine from Z.pm ?

Comment: Never pass a .pm directly to `perl`. Use `perl -e'use X::Y::Z;'` instead, although you actually need `perl -e'use lib "/Users/myname/Documents/blabla/ccccc/ggg/x/lib"; use X::Y::Z;'`

Comment: If you create the script in `x`, you need `use FindBin 1.51 qw( $RealBin ); use lib "$RealBin/lib";`.

Comment: If you create the script in `x/lib`, you need `use FindBin 1.51 qw( $RealBin ); use lib $RealBin;`.

Comment: If you create the script in `x/bin`, you need `use FindBin 1.51 qw( $RealBin ); use lib "$RealBin/../lib";`.

Comment: adding use lib "/Users/myname/Documents/blabla/ccccc/ggg/x/lib solved the issue. let me try your FindBin solution as well

Comment: You could do that, but most people would prefer not using an absolute path like that.

Comment: sad  I don't have permission to upvote your soution :(

Comment: No worries. It didn't work because the base dir wasn't in `@INC`. (`.` wasn't the base dir.)